# Cohomology of Beauville–Mukai varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, holomorphic-symplectic

The rational second cohomology of the Hilbert scheme on a K3 surface $S$ are spanned by $H^2(S,\mathbb{Q})$ plus the class of the exceptional divisor. The mapping $H^2(S, \mathbb{Q}) \to H^2(\mathrm{Hilb}^n(S),\mathbb{Q})$ is the composition of the isomorphism $H^2(S,\mathbb{Q}) \to \left(H^2(S,\mathbb{Q})^{\oplus n}\right)^{S_n} = H^2(S^{(n)},\mathbb{Q})$ and the pullback along the blowup of the diagonal $\mathrm{Hilb}^n(S) \to S^{(n)}$.

We also know that the Beauville–Mukai varieties $\overline{\mathrm{Jac}}^d(S,|C|)$ (parametrizing sheaves on $S$ with certain Mukai vector, typical such sheaf being a degree $d$ line bundle supported on a curve from the linear system $|C|$) have deformation type of the Hilbert schemes. In some cases, e. g. when $d$ equals the genus of $C$, it is even birational isomorphic to the Hilbert scheme.

The question is: can we relate the second cohomology of $\overline{\mathrm{Jac}}^d(S,|C|)$ to the second cohomology of $S$ in an explicit manner? Indeed, we can make it for Hodge classes orthogonal to $[C]$ via Fourier–Mukai transform: if $L \to S$ is a line bundle with $L.C = 0$, it defines a point in $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$ for any $C \in |C|$, and thus a line bundle on the compactified relative Jacobian (which becomes trivial when restricted to each fiber—that corresponds to $L.C = 0$). However, I don't see how to make this work for non-Hodge classes.

And the naïve follow-up question: if we could describe a map $H^2(S,\mathbb{Q}) \to H^2\left(\overline{\mathrm{Jac}}^d(S,|C|),\mathbb{Q}\right)$ geometrically, can it be written with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients? What should we multiply the BBF form on $H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$ by to get the restriction of the BBF form on $H^2\left(\overline{\mathrm{Jac}}^d(S,|C|),\mathbb{Z}\right)$ to the image of $H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$?